# How can I write a batch file to run a specific command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a batch file that will run the following command:
`control name Microsoft.Personalization page pageWallpaper`

How do I do this?

EDIT: I should be more specific. I know how to create a batch file but all I have written in the file is the code above, which just flashes a window and then does nothing.

Comment: Have you looked into batch files at all? This is like the main purpose of them, so material on the topic should be readily available.

Comment: Open the batch from a cmd and not by double clicking it. This should show you what is happening and if there possibly is an error message to be seen

Comment: @Marged I did that, all it does is show the command I have written in the batch file in the console window, and then creates a new line.

Comment: Are you sure the command does anything at all ? Does it work when run outside that batch ?

Comment: @Marged Yes. Running it in cmd does exactly what I want it to.

Comment: Are you perhaps missing some slashes when calling the command ? For example in /name. You could try an absolute path to control.exe and printing the errorlevel

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you need:

```
@echo off
control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper
```

The syntax of `control.exe` requires the slashes before `name` and `page`.

Source: [Add classic personalization menu in Windows 10 build 10074](http://winaero.com/blog/add-classic-personalization-menu-in-windows-10-build-10074/)

Also, [Command Line Commands for Control Panel Applets](https://www.lifewire.com/command-line-commands-for-control-panel-applets-2626060) helped lead me to the answer.

I started by googling "windows control.exe command line options".

You know how to create batch files, but if you have any trouble putting the code above into a batch file and running it, and cannot figure out how, please let me know.

This works for me, running:

```
C:\bin> ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
```

Hope it works for you!

Regards,
Lud nom

Comment: I hope this answer was helpful! If it answered your question, I'd really appreciate it if you marked it as the answer. If not, please let me know, and I'll see what I can do to help.